# Difference between $x, $[x], ${x} in bash

Tags: bash, shell

When I test a script bellow:

```
#!/bin/bash

num1=100
num2=100


if test $num1 -eq $num2  # there is no difference using $num1 ,$[num1] and ${num1}
then 
    echo "equal"    
else
    echo "not equal"    
fi
```

I know if we echo the variable, we should use the `{}` to define the periphery, but how about the `[]`? Does `[]` some difference with `{}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$x` and `${x}` have the same semantics, the braces are never needed, but they might be convenient when you need to separate the variable from a string following it:

```
var=program
echo "${var}s"  # $vars wouldn't work
```

`$[x]` is an old way of writing `$((x))`, i.e. result of an arithmetic expression.

```
x=3
y=2
echo $(( x + y ))  # 5
```

For more details, see [Why should I use $[ EXPR ] instead of $(( EXPR ))?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/81599/13792).

Comment: So, if I want to arithmetic expression I can use `$(( x + y ))` or `$[ x + y ]` , all is fine, right?

Comment: `$[...]` is deprecated, which means it might be removed in a future version of bash, so `$((...))` is safer.

Comment: thanks, this make sense .